# Ordering results from Graph API (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I writing scenario that gets from Facebook group last posts and saves to DB of my application.
I make request to Facebook:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/[group_id]/feed?since=1417341180&limit=50
```

I expect  50 last posts since `1417341180` (this is timestamp) from group wall, but Facebook returns posts that ordering by updated_time, but I need ordering by created_time.
How I can solve with problem? Maybe exist order parameter?

Example:
[image]

Comment: It is currently not possible

Comment: How I can solve It? Do I have get big number of posts and check each element?

Comment: Yes that is the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, ordering on `created_time` is not possible. You'll need to order the posts in your application unfortunately.

Comment: Still can't I use ordering?